# Display address in single column instead of each line of address in its own column

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template whth the following:

```
<td th:text="${tempUser.addressLine1}" />
<td th:text="${tempUser.addressLine2}" />
<td th:text="${tempUser.town}" />
<td th:text="${tempUser.county}" />
<td th:text="${tempUser.country}" />
<td th:text="${tempUser.postcode}" />
```

Each line of the address gets output to  different column. How can I change this so my Entire address is displayed in a single column in the format:

```
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Town
County
Country
Post Code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need tables you can do it like this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/*
.container > span {
  display: block;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span th:text="${tempUser.addressLine1}"></span>
  <span th:text="${tempUser.addressLine2}"> </span>
  <span th:text="${tempUser.town}"> </span>
  <span th:text="${tempUser.county}"></span>
  <span th:text="${tempUser.country}"></span>
  <span th:text="${tempUser.postcode}"></span>
</div>
```